# Grails 3 Cookie plugin not found

Tags: grails

I want to use the Grails 3 Cookie plugin (http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/ctoestreich/cookie). In my `build.gradle` I have these entries here:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    [...]
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-cookie:2.0.5'
    [...]
}
```

But when running `gradle build`, he's got problems looking up that dependency:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
   > Could not find org.grails.plugins:grails-cookie:2.0.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/marp/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/grails-cookie/2.0.5/grails-cookie-2.0.5.pom
         file:/home/marp/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/grails-cookie/2.0.5/grails-cookie-2.0.5.jar
         https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/grails-cookie/2.0.5/grails-cookie-2.0.5.pom
         https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/grails-cookie/2.0.5/grails-cookie-2.0.5.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/grails-cookie/2.0.5/grails-cookie-2.0.5.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/grails-cookie/2.0.5/grails-cookie-2.0.5.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

Do I need to include an other maven repo? Or is the plugin just gone?

Comment: If I see this correctly, this should be working just fine: http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/ctoestreich/cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-cookie:2.0.5'`

use `compile 'org.grails.plugins:cookie:2.0.5'`

also you can set cookie expiration configuration in `application.yml` file
Example-`grails.plugins.cookie.cookieage.default: 43200`

[repo of dependency](http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cookie/)

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

According to this (at the time of writing), 2.0.3 appears to be the newest version on the repo.grails.org repo:
http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/grails-cookie/

change your dependency to:

```
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:cookie:2.0.3'
```